Can I programmatically insert office add-in manifest file in an Word web App?
i have a question.
can I programmatically insert office add-in manifest file in an Word web App?
We have a office manifest file updated with correct name of hosting server and the office add-in is hosted on Azure WebApp, When user click new button from my web app I want to open office and 1st want to add manifest file in Add-In.
I want to grammatically add manifest file in Word web app.
let me know if its possible to addin office addin through manifest file in an Word programmatically.
